# How does this math notation work?

Tags: notation

I am trying to solve this question involving a notation im not sure how to use in the context of the question.

I used the equation (2GMX)/(a^2) x (1/x - 1/sqrt(x^2+a^2)) where G is the gravitational constant, M is the mass, a is the radius and x is distance.

I have been asked to use this formula when x<<a, and no x value has been given.

How do i manipulate the formula to simplify the equation to satisfy this? I have not really come across this before.

Comment: [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) would make this clearer, but I have two questions: (1) is your first lower-case x a factor of $x$ or a multiplication sign? (2) Is the upper-case X meant to be lower case?

Comment: ...when $x$ is much smaller conpared to $a$.

Answer (score 1):

When $x\ll a$,$$\frac1x-\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}\approx\frac1x-\frac{1}{|a|}\approx\frac{1}{x}.$$

Comment: thanks, i understand this now! much appreciated!!